# Convert YAML to TOML and place in archetypes/default.md with Hugo

Tags: yaml, hugo, toml

I have Hugo markdown pages with Front Matter that successfully add themselves to the menu. The markdown is in YAML format.

```
menu:
  main:
      parent: 'products'
      identifier: 'newitem'
      name: "New Item"
```

This yields a menu that has a New Item sitting under the products item.

I want to extract this menu front matter into the archetype, so that when I create a new item, it creates the menu structure for me and I just need to change the identifier.

This is the TOML I converted the original YAML to.

```
[[menu.main]]
parent = "products"
identifier = "newitem"
name = "New Item"
```

However when I create a new item, the menu item sits as a sibling to `products` rather than under products.

The output from the `Hugo new` process is this:

```
[menu]

  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "newitem"
    name = "New Item"
    parent = "products"
```

What am I doing wrong?